# Why does vim tell me that I added an autocommand?

Tags: autocmd

I have been changing "$OLD" to "~/new" in a lot of files lately, so I am now used to starting vim like this

```
$ vim file.txt
```

<kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
Lorem ipsum $OLD
Lorem .OLD ipsum
```

<kbd>:</kbd><kbd>%</kbd><kbd>up</kbd> (brings back `%s:\$OLD:\~/new:gc`)<kbd>Enter</kbd>

<kbd>:</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
$
```

So I added a new autocommand in ~/.vimrc, like this

```
if has("autocmd")
  au BufEnter %s:\$OLD:\~/new:gc
endif
```

and this

```
  au BufEnter :%s:\$OLD:\~/new:gc
```

And next time I tried vim, it wasn't as impressed as I was hoping:

```
$ vim file.txt
```

<kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
--- Auto-Commands ---
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

<kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
Lorem ipsum $OLD
Lorem .OLD ipsum
```

<kbd>:</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
$
```

Why is vim just telling me about the commands, instead of running them?

Comment: Found some help at "[Learn Vimscript the Hard Way](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/12.html)"

Comment: `autocmd FileType sh nnoremap <F3> :%s:\$OLD:\~/new:gc<cr>` works for me, but doesn't answer the question of what I did wrong the first time round

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't provide a pattern to `au`. Note [the syntax](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#%3Aau):

```
:au[tocmd] [group] {event} {pat} [nested] {cmd}
                        Add {cmd} to the list of commands that Vim will
                        execute automatically on {event} for a file matching
                        {pat} autocmd-patterns.

:au[tocmd] [group] {event} {pat}
                        Show the autocommands associated with {event} and
                        {pat}.
```

The first adds an autocommand, and the second lists autocommands. That's why you got that output.

Answer (score 4):

You should change:

```
au BufEnter %s:\$OLD:\~/new:gc
```

to:

```
au BufEnter * %s:\$OLD:\~/new:gc
```

or something else.